# What type of a PDE $-Lu = g(u)$ compared to $-Lu = g(x,u)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

As far as I know, when $L$ is linear the pde $-Lu = g(x,u)$ is described as "semilinear". Is there a different word for $-Lu = g(u)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called *autonomous semilinear* equations. [One of many examples](http://www.capde.cl/archivos/publicaciones/paperproceedingsICMMdP.pdf).